# Can't edit title or tags when improving suggested edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I decided to give the suggested edits review queue a spin after finding out about the recent [robo reviewer countermeasures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238039/234299). My first review was a great candidate for improvement: indentation was fixed but grammar and spelling were not. The title also left something to be desired.

Imagine my horror when I clicked <kbd>Improve</kbd> and saw this:

[image]

I don't spend a ton of time in the suggested edits queue, but I seem to remember being able to improve the title and tags *as well as* the post body. It would be ironic if I unchecked the helpful box for an edit suggestion and then failed to make all of the necessary changes myself.

Comment: Ahh, I wanted to take a look myself by clicking Improve on a random suggested edit, and of course it had to be an audit...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The suggested edit is for an answer, so you only get to edit the answer itself.

When improving a suggested edit for a question, you will be able to edit the title and tags.

Comment: Doh! I was so excited that I had the review all to myself for a few minutes that I completely failed to notice that it was an answer.